# Displaying DateTime.Hour with AM or PM attached

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to display the hour along with AM or PM in for a grid view control using a LINQ query. The issue is that the system cannot handle the concatenated string along with the DateTime variables. Here is my LINQ query:

```
var data = (from x in context.Races
            where x.RaceDate.Year == selectedDate.Year && x.RaceDate.Month == selectedDate.Month && 
            x.RaceDate.Day == selectedDate.Day
                            select new RegistrationSchedule
                            {
                                RaceDate = x.RaceDate.Hour <= 11 ? x.RaceDate.Hour + " AM" : x.RaceDate.Hour + " PM",
                                Comment = x.Certification.Description + " - " + x.Comment,
                                Run = char.Parse(x.Run),
                                NumberOfCars = x.NumberOfCars
                            }
                 );

                return data.ToList();
```

What I am trying to display in the query result should look like "10 AM" for instance, where if the hour is before 11 the system will add AM to it. Setting up the query in Linqpad the system had no trouble concatenating the DateTime with the attached strings. I have tried to find some information on how to convert the DateTime object to display AM or PM but have not found anything that might work within the query. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format strings to print a date in any format you like:

```cs
void Print12Hour(DateTime dateTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{dateTime:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt});
}
```

Here `hh` will give you the hours in 12-hour format and `tt` is the AM/PM suffix.

Comment: I am trying to display only the hour and AM/PM from the x.RaceDate.Hour object in the query above. Whereby if the hour is less than 11 it displays AM and or PM if it is greater. How can I modify the method you show here to accomplish that? I'm pretty new to coding, so I apologize if this seems really simple.

Comment: You can modify the format string. `$"{dateTime:hh tt}"` will print only the hours and the AM/PM suffix. So you want `$"{x.RaceDate:hh tt}"`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry it took so long to get back to you. What I ended up doing on the webpage was modifying the string like you suggested:
```<asp:Label Text='<%# string.Format("{0:c}",Eval("RaceFee")) %>' runat="server" ID="RaceFeeLabel" />``` 
The only difference was that to initialize the variable I had to use 0 instead of dateTime. I found some helpful info at https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/ for using string.Format to change the displayed data with regards to dateTime

Answer (score 2):

You should not attempt to concatenate a `string`(AM/PM literals) to `DateTime` . Instead, you should format the display of DateTime to the required format when you are displaying it.

To display the Hour along with AM/PM, following should be useful.

```
Console.WriteLine( dateTime.ToString("h tt"));
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine( $"{dateTime:h tt}");
```